# How to get this table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema:

[image]

And I want to generate a table with 3 columns - tag's name, thread's name, answers count.

Example:

```
Foo bar 5
Foo something 6
Foo2 somethingElse 3
```

What's more, there's a table "priority_threads" (1:1 with threads). I want to display only those priority threads in this table.

How can I do this? I have absolutely no idea how to even start. The only thing I did is:

```
SELECT tag.name, thread.title, COUNT(answer.id_answer)
FROM tag, thread, answer
WHERE thread.id_tag = tag.id_tag 
AND answer.id_thread = thread.id_thread
AND thread.id_thread = priority_threads.id_thread
GROUP BY tag.name, thread.title
ORDER BY tag.name;
```

However using this query all values in the answer's count column are the same - count(*) from Answer table...

Comment: Don't use implicit/comma-join syntax. Use explicit JOIN syntax instead.

Comment: @user2252786  is your question solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT tag.name, thread.title, COUNT(answer.id_answer)
FROM tag
JOIN thread ON
tag.id_tag=thread.id_tag
JOIN answer ON
    thread.id_thread = answer.id_thread
JOIN priority_threads
ON thread.id_thread = priority_threads.id_thread
GROUP BY tag.name, thread.title
ORDER BY tag.name;
```

Here is a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9884/2) link to the query to test it out;

Sample code:

```
 CREATE TABLE Tag
    (
 id_tag int auto_increment primary key, 
 name varchar(20)
 );

INSERT INTO Tag
(name)
VALUES
('Foo'), 
('Foo2');

CREATE TABLE Thread
    (
 id_thread int auto_increment primary key, 
 id_tag int, 
 title varchar(20)
 );

INSERT INTO Thread
(id_tag, title)
VALUES
(1,'Bar'), 
(1,'Something'),
(2,'SomethingElse');

CREATE TABLE Answer
    (
 id_answer int auto_increment primary key, 
 id_thread int,
 text varchar(200)
 );

INSERT INTO Answer
(id_thread, text)
VALUES
(1,'jlkjalkjl'), 
(1,'ioioixhakjjkj'),
(1, 'jjalkjijkajk'),
(1, 'jjalkjijkajk'),
(1, 'jjalkjijkajk'),
(2, 'jjalkjijkajk'),
(2, 'jjalkjijkajk'),
(2, 'jjalkjijkajk'),
(2, 'qqweeweraata'),
(2, 'jjalkjijkajk'),
(2, 'jjalkjijkajk'),
(3, 'popoapopop'),
(3, 'zkkasjkljz'),
(3, 'jjalkjijkajk')
;

CREATE TABLE priority_threads
    (
 id_priority_threads int auto_increment primary key, 
 id_thread int, 
 priority int
 );

INSERT INTO priority_threads
(id_thread, priority)
VALUES
(1,1), 
(3,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

so:

```
    SELECT tag.name, thread.title, COUNT(answer.id_answer)
FROM tag, thread, answer
WHERE thread.id_tag = tag.id_tag 
AND answer.id_thread = thread.id_thread
GROUP BY tag.name, thread.title
ORDER BY tag.name;
```

can look like this:

```
SELECT tag.name, thread.title, COUNT(answer.id_answer)
FROM tag
JOIN thread ON
tag.id_tag=thread.id_tag
JOIN answer ON
    thread.id_thread = answer.id_thread
GROUP BY tag.name, thread.title
ORDER BY tag.name;
```

The results are the same, the former is preferred by most.  Okay, but I think the real issue here is this line here in your posted code:

AND thread.id_thread = priority_threads.id_thread

you are referencing another table, priority_threads, which is not in your query. Either add the join or remove it and you should be good to go.

-james